# How to execute command without storing it in history (even for "up" key) in zsh

Tags: zsh, command-history

People mentioned using `preexec` hook in zsh, but how exactly should I use it? I mean, okay I can check for every command whether or not it's the command I want to not show up in history, but what to do after that?

Answer (score 3):

By default `zsh` always keeps the last command in session history, even when setting `HISTSIZE=0`. You could write your own widget to circumvent the history mechanism.

```sh
sneaky-run () {   
    echo
    eval $BUFFER
    BUFFER=''
    zle reset-prompt
}

zle -N sneaky-run
bindkey '^X^M' sneaky-run
```

This the widget `sneaky-run` will run the currently typed command, then empty the command buffer and reset the prompt.
Commands that are run within a widget are not added to the history.

The `echo` at the beginning is needed so that the output starts in a new line. If you have a multi-line prompt you may need to add additional `echo`s  for each additional line just before `zle reset-prompt`, otherwise the prompt might overwrite a few lines of the command output.

For this example `sneaky-run` is bound to the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

If you do not want to use an extra key combination for that, you can also wrap the `accept-line` widget, which is usually bound to <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```sh
accept-line-with-sneaky () {   
    if [[ "$BUFFER" == "${BUFFER#" } ]] ; then
        zle accept-line
    else
        echo
        eval $BUFFER
        BUFFER=''
        zle reset-prompt
    fi
}

zle -N accept-line-with-sneaky
bindkey '^M' accept-line-with-sneaky
```

This mimics the behavior of setting `HIST_IGNORE_SPACE`: If a command starts with a space, it will not be added to the history. But other than with `HIST_IGNORE_SPACE` it will also not be available when pressiong <kbd>Up</kbd>.

**Note:** this will override one of the most fundamental key bindings of `zsh`. So please test thoroughly before putting this in your `~/.zshrc`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `HIST_IGNORE_SPACE` option.

```
setopt HIST_IGNORE_SPACE
```

or set it in your profile and then prefix the commands you don't want stored with a space.

Comment: @Dababi What should work `setopt HIST_IGNORE_SPACE`? Are you saying that you've started zsh with this option set, then entered some command prefixed with space, pressed `enter` and then pressed `up` key and your prompt isn't filled with the previous command?

Comment: yes it worked for me

Comment: @user1685095 If you press Up immediately then the previous command is recalled, even if it began with a space. But if you enter another command then the command that began with a space is no longer accessible.

Comment: @Gilles I know. I want to enter only one command, that wouldn't be in history. Two isn't good enough.